# Setting the value of a dynamically created text box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following code

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));
var newTextBox;

newTextBox = $(document.createElement("input"))
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("id", "textbox")
    .attr("name", "textbox");

newTextBox.val("text");
newDiv.append(newTextBox);
alert(newDiv.html());
```

I get the following

```
<input name="textbox" id="textbox" type="text">
```

I get the same thing with

```
$("#textbox").val("test");
```

Using

```
newTextBox = $("<input/>");
```

Doesn't help either

Where is my value?

**EDIT: SOLTUION**

So, further up in the stack I was converting the DOM I built to a string and since - like munch mentioned - the dynamic value doesn't get added to the tag, it wasn't showing up.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about chaining `.attr('value', 'text')` in the declaration? The latter prob doesn't work before you've injected the object into the DOM.

Comment: I've tried several things to get this to work, interestingly, it does not. Neither @nikc's nor @TiuTalk's suggestions make a difference. I'm intrigued.

Comment: It's interesting because if I do an alert(newTextBox.val()); it shows the correct value before and after injecting it into the div

Comment: I'm starting to think *bug* but I might be crazy. Still trying to see the mysterious value in an alert box.

Comment: You're not inserting the div. Could that be the cause?

Comment: @nikc - I tried appending the div to `<body>` and the result was still the same.

Comment: @nikc I'm not showing the part in my code where I insert the dive into another div and display in the body, but the value doesn't show up when I do it there either

Comment: @Mason, if this little bit of code is working for everyone else, my guess is the error is someplace different. Maybe the value is being reset somehow? We could probably be more help if you posted the rest of it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery will not put the value into the created element's generated html. Both `.attr('value', 'blah')` and `.val()` get the current value of what's been entered or changed in the text input, and allow you to see that value when you look at the input on the page or submit it to the server. However, you will not see it when looking at the html.

You can still manipulate the value all you want, you just won't see any changes in firebug, like you do with class changes, styling, etc.

AFAIK, this is the same without using jQuery. The same thing happens with:

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value = 'my text';
```

The value attribute is only to set something's value from the server. It's not needed with javascript.

Also, it depends on the type of input that you're using. For example, you will see the value attribute changes with a hidden input, but not with the textbox.

EDIT:

By appending newDiv to the body, the text box and the value show up using your code. [Here's a test page](http://jsbin.com/ayoca/edit). You can see both the code and the preview of what happens. The alert though, does not show any 'value' attribute for reasons explained above.

Comment: So then it's impossible to dynamically create a text box and set the value in it and have it display to the user (via the DOM, obviously string concatenation would work)?

Comment: The value will always display to the user looking at the text box. You won't see the value when looking at the html. The reason you don't see any generated output is because you're not appending newDiv to an element currently on the page, ie. 'body')...see the revision to my answer

Comment: Yeah hm so I must have another issue and happened to run into this while debugging it.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help munch, I added the answer to my OP

Answer (score 2):

```
var newDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));

var newTextBox = $('<input />')
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("id", "textbox")
    .attr("name", "textbox")
    .val("my text"); // <-- You can use here...

newTextBox.val("my text"); // <-- or here
newDiv.append(newTextBox);
alert(newDiv.html());
```

Comment: Nope... still not seeing the value as being set

Comment: Try: alert($("#textbox").html());

Comment: That gives me the right value but isn't very useful since I'm trying to inject this into the DOM.  I've distilled my actual usage into the simplest example possible.  Edit:  it would be $("#textbox").val()) since it's an input but I understand what you meant.

Comment: This did work when I tried it, both in IE7 and FF 3.6. What are you using, Mason? You may want to expand on "doesn't work" also.

Comment: You need to use the selector #textbox again because the newTextBox var is just a DOM element that isn't inside your HTML.. The use of append() don't modify the newTextBox.. Perhaps you can do this with jQuery 1.4.x: newTextBox = newDiv.append(newTextBox); alert(newTextBox.val());

Answer (score 1):

With a little hack you can do it ..

```
var newDiv = $('<div/>');
var newTextBox;

newTextBox = $('<input/>')
    .attr("type", "hidden")
    .attr("id", "textbox")
    .attr("name", "textbox");

newTextBox.val("text");
newDiv.append(newTextBox);
newTextBox.each(function(){this.type='text';});
alert(newDiv.html());
```

1st define its type as hidden, because this will allow the value attribute, and then using code change it to text ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#element")[0].setAttribute("value","newvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also do this

`var chip = document.createElement("div");
chip.innerHTML="some value here"
card.appendChild(chip)`