# How to display value for dynamically generated text box

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a dialog with a form displaying details of an object. There is x dynamically generated h:inputtext if there is x number of values to be displayed. The values don't appear in the text boxes however, they appear in the browser console using JavaScript to get the value of the text boxes. How do I show the values in the respective text boxes?

From the bean, a map containing the ids of the text boxes and their respective values is passed to the view. When the document finishes loading, jquery is used to retrieve the values and then assign them to the text boxes.

Below is the view:

```html
<ui:repeat var="a" value="#{managedBean.listA}">
    <ui:repeat var="b" value="#{a.listBofA}">
        <input class="form-control" value="#{managedBean.getABs(b, a)}" id="A_B_ID_#{a.id}_#{b.id}" name="A_B_ID_#{a.id}_#{b.id}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var folders = $.parseJSON('#{managedBean.foldersMap}');
        $.each(folders, function( index, value ){
            $('#A_B_ID_'+index).val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please provide a minimal code snippet showing what you do and what you expected to be the outcome

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: And this is not a dynamically generated `h:inputText` but a plain html input

Comment: thank you @Kukeltje for the correction. I decided to test it with the regular text box but that also didn't work.

Comment: found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158954/setting-the-value-of-a-dynamically-created-text-box-with-jquery